# Evaluation of mock modular forms at elliptic points

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, theta-functions, periods, theta-series

The holomorphic function
$$F(\tau)=-\frac{1}{\vartheta_4(\tau)}\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\frac{(-1)^nq^{\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac 18}}{1-q^{n-\frac12}}=2q^{\frac38}(1+3q^{\frac12}+7q+14q^{\frac32}+\dots),$$
is a mock modular form for the congruence subgroup $\Gamma^0(4)$ of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ with shadow $\eta^3$. Here,   $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$, $\vartheta_4(\tau)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}(-1)^n q^{n^2/2}$ is a Jacobi theta function and $\eta$ is the Dedekind eta function. The $q$-series is the OEIS sequence A256209.

As a consequence, the sum of $F$ and a non-holomorphic period integral
$$ \hat F(\tau,\bar\tau)=F(\tau)-\frac i2\int_{-\bar\tau}^{i\infty}\frac{\eta(w)^3}{\sqrt{-i(w+\tau)}}\mathrm dw. $$
transforms as a non-holomorphic modular form of weight $(\tfrac12,0)$ for $\Gamma^0(4)$, and it is clear that $\partial_{\bar\tau}\hat F(\tau,\bar\tau)=-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{2y}}\overline{\eta(\tau)^3}$.

I am interested in special values of $F$ and $\hat F$, such as at the elliptic points of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$. For instance, numerically I find that
$$\hat F(i,\bar i)=\frac{\vartheta_4(i)}{2^{\frac54}}, \\
\hat F(\alpha,\bar\alpha)=\frac{e^{-\frac{\pi i}{4}}\vartheta_4(\alpha)}{2\sqrt3},$$
where $\alpha=e^{2\pi i/3}$, while $\hat F(i+1,\overline{i+1})=0$. The latter can be proven by realising that $\hat F$ is more precisely a non-holomorphic modular form for $\Gamma^0(2)$, whose multiplier system evaluated at the elliptic fixed point $1+i$ of $\Gamma^0(2)$ is $-1$.

My questions:

- Are explicit values of mock modular forms and their completions at elliptic points known in the literature?
- Is there a general strategy to calculate series and period integrals, such as those involved in $\hat F(i,\bar i)$ and $\hat F(\alpha,\bar\alpha)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The holomorphic function $F$ is related to the $q$-series $H^{(2)}$ of Mathieu moonshine in a simple way. We have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    H^{(2)}(\tau)&=2\frac{\vartheta_2(\tau)^4-\vartheta_4(\tau)^4}{\eta(\tau)^3}-\frac{24}{\vartheta_3(\tau)}\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\frac{q^{\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac18}}{1+q^{n-\frac12}}\\
    &=2q^{-\frac18}\left(-1+45q+231q^2+770q^3+2277q^4+\dots\right)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The $q$-series is the   OEIS sequence A169717, and the Fourier coefficients are sums of dimensions of irreducible representations of the sporadic group $M_{24}$. It relates to $F$ as
\begin{equation}\label{FH_relation}
    F(\tau)=\frac{1}{24}\left( H^{(2)}(\tau)+2\frac{\vartheta_2(\tau)^4+\vartheta_3(\tau)^4}{\eta(\tau)^3}\right).
\end{equation}
Since both $H^{(2)}$ and $F$ are mock modular forms with shadow $\eta^3$, their non-holomorphic completions $\widehat H^{(2)}$ and $\widehat F$ are simply related by
\begin{equation}\label{FhatHhat}
    \widehat F(\tau)=\frac{1}{24}\left( \widehat H^{(2)}(\tau)+2\frac{\vartheta_2(\tau)^4+\vartheta_3(\tau)^4}{\eta(\tau)^3}\right).
\end{equation}
Unlike $ \widehat F$, $\widehat H^{(2)}$ is a non-holomorphic modular function for $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$, and transforms under the generators as
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \widehat H^{(2)}(\tau+1,\bar\tau+1)&=e^{-\frac{\pi i}{4}}\widehat H^{(2)}(\tau,\bar\tau), \\
    \widehat H^{(2)}(-1/\tau,-1/\bar\tau)&=-\sqrt{-i\tau}\widehat H^{(2)}(\tau,\bar\tau).
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
From the phases of the transformations under the elliptic elements of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ stabilising the elliptic fixed points $i$ and $\alpha$, we easily find
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
  \widehat H^{(2)}(i,\bar i)&=0, \\
 \widehat H^{(2)}(\alpha,\bar \alpha)&=0.
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
Thus at $\tau=i$ and $\tau=\alpha$ the completion $ \widehat H^{(2)}(\tau,\bar\tau)$ evaluates to the modular "difference" between $ \widehat H^{(2)}$ and $\widehat F$, which can be determined using the Chowla-Selberg formula.